# How do they differ in meaning: "d’eux-même", "eux-même" and "par eux-même"?

Tags: usage

I’d like to find out which one of these three is appropriate to use in the sentence below.

> - Ils ont décidé d’aller à la ville pour vérifier ***d’eux-même*** la terrible nouvelle.
> - Ils ont décidé d’aller à la ville pour vérifier ***eux-même*** la terrible nouvelle.
> - Ils ont décidé d’aller à la ville pour vérifier ***par eux-même*** la terrible nouvelle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Par eux-mêmes** is the most common and slightly more formal:

> Ils ont décidé d’aller à la ville pour vérifier **par eux-mêmes** la terrible nouvelle.

The simpler *eux-mêmes* is still correct and usable:

> Ils ont décidé d’aller à la ville pour vérifier **eux-mêmes** la terrible nouvelle.

I would avoid *d'eux-mêmes*, at least because it sounds like *de même*.

Note that *même* is an adjective here and then needs to agree with *eux* which is plural, so it is *eux-mêmes* in all cases.